# Htaccess blank page in subdomain

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a cms wordpress blog, and a subdomain associated with vbulletin forum with a folder domain.com/comunidad/. When i enter to my subdomain "comunidad.cssblog.es" it shows a blank page, happens the same if I enter directly to the folder "domain.com/comunidad/, but if I enter with "comunidad.cssblog.es/index.php" or "domain.com/comunidad/index.php", its work goods and can enter, how i can solve this?

My htaccess in the folder comunidad is:

```
# Comment the following line (add '#' at the beginning)
# to disable mod_rewrite functions.
# Please note: you still need to disable the hack in
# the vBSEO control panel to stop url rewrites.
RewriteEngine On

# Some servers require the Rewritebase directive to be
# enabled (remove '#' at the beginning to activate)
# Please note: when enabled, you must include the path
# to your root vB folder (i.e. RewriteBase /forums/)
#RewriteBase /index.php

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/forums/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^((urllist|sitemap_).*\.(xml|txt)(\.gz)?)$ vbseo_sitemap/vbseo_getsitemap.php?sitemap=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(admincp/|modcp/|cron|vbseo_sitemap)
RewriteRule ^((archive/)?(.*\.php(/.*)?))$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(admincp|modcp|clientscript|cpstyles|images)/
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ vbseo.php [L,QSA]
```

My htaccess in main domain is:

```
# Si se accede desde
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} comunidad.cssblog.es
# Y la carpeta solicitada no es "comunidad"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !comunidad/
# accedemos directamente a la carpeta mi/la_url_indicada
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ comunidad/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sounds like the virtual host for that subdomain does not have the correct configuration for the `DocumentIndex` directive: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: BTW: rewrite rules and conditions work on _regular expressions_, not on string matches. So it should be `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^comunidad\.cssblog\.es$` instead of `comunidad.cssblog.es`.

Comment: Its still shows blank page with that change, sorry.

Comment: What change are you referring to?

Comment: I changed this line:  "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} comunidad.cssblog.es" to "RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^comunidad\.cssblog\.es$"

Comment: Blank page = Error (Display error is switched off).

Comment: I did not claim that would solve the issue. "BTW" stands for "by the way", so it was a general remark meant independent from the current issue you face. Please consider what I wrote in my _first_ comment which _did_ refer to the current issue.

Comment: Often, indeed, though it can also simply be an empty page sent out by the server ;-) However the hint is correct: @Pedro you definitely should check your http servers error log file to read what the _specific_ issue is your http server runs into when processing those requests.

Comment: I tried to create a index.html file in the folder /comunidad/ with some text and now when i access on comunidad.cssblog.es or cssblog.es/comunidad/ don't show blank page, shows the text that i wrote in the index.html, so i think is not a "blank page because error".